# Locking properties vs Locking the entire object. Which is better for performance?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing a triggerbot and I'm creating a class called settings that contain private variables (all the controls in the form) and public properties (bools and ints)

```
public class Settings
{
    private BunifuCustomTextbox xOffsetTB;
    private BunifuCustomTextbox yOffsetTB;
    private BunifuCustomTextbox scanIntervalTB;
    private BunifuCustomTextbox rClickIntervalTB;
    private BunifuCustomTextbox snipeWatiTimeTB;
    private BunifuCustomTextbox arrowWaitTimeTB;
    private BunifuCheckbox closeRangeRClickCB;
    private BunifuCheckbox longRangeRClickCB;
    private BunifuCheckbox closeRangeLClickCB;
    private BunifuCheckbox longRangeLClickCB;
    private BunifuSwitch kinessaModeCB;
    private BunifuSwitch shalinModeCB;
    private BunifuiOSSwitch DrawCB;
    private BunifuiOSSwitch DisableOnShiftCB;

    public int xOffset { get; set; }
    public int yOffset { get; set; }
    public int scanInterval { get; set; }
    public int rClickInterval { get; set; }
    public int snipeWaitTime { get; set; }
    public int arrowWaitTime { get; set; }
    public bool closeRangeRClick { get; set; }
    public bool longRangeRClick { get; set; }
    public bool closeRangeLClick { get; set; }
    public bool kinessaMode { get; set; }
    public bool shalinMode { get; set; }
    public bool draw { get; set; }
    public bool disableOnShift { get; set; }

}
```

I'll be writing the get set statements that will get the value from the controls and set the values to the controls.

I want the program to update on the fly as the user changes the input there for I should lock either the entire Settings class or each individual property in the Settings class. Which would be the better choice in terms of performance ?

Note that I do know that I'll have to Invoke the main thread to change the values in the controls. I also know that the thread using these properties should creates it's own private copy of the variables and release the lock before trying to do anything else. My main concern is the performance and if I lock the settings class within an infinite loop with no Thread.Sleep(xx); is there a possibility that, that thread will always have the settings variable locked ? cause something similar happened while I was experimenting on another project

Comment: "I lock the settings class within an infinite loop with no Thread.Sleep(xx); ". Thread.Sleep will not release any locks

Comment: Users are slower than machines, by a factor of about one billion. Do you have a billion concurrent users? If not, what you should aim for is a design that's obviously correct with regards to synchronization, and leave the performance for the day when (if) tests show there's a bottleneck. In other words, lock the world, it's simpler. Now, if you're writing a kernel, you may want to spend time [thinking about this up front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_lock), but that's quite a different problem domain.

Comment: The `Thread.Sleep(xx)` question would make sense for lockless algorithms (i.e. spinning), since you want to ensure that other threads get the chance to update a volatile value. However, with locking, there is no spinning, a thread either enters the section, or gets queued. But the fact that you are "locking inside an infinite loop with thread sleeps" sounds bad.

Comment: Btw, are you sure it wouldn't be simpler to use [DataBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding)?

Comment: Yeah, DataBinding  looks like a good feed.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @Groo I meant
for(;;)
{
   lock(_Lock)
   {
   //Do things
   }
   Thread.Sleep(xx);
}

Comment: Thanks for the data binding suggestion. I didn't know that was a thing

Answer (score 0):

Performance-wise I'm pretty sure that is the same performance. When you use lock(object), you are using the reference number to create an exclusion zone, and any other lock over the same object will require the first to complete. What are you achieving with this approach, is to avoid collisions between user updating different field. Also, the possible benefits from concurrency can be added back by the overhead of having the multiple exclusion zones. Do a small experiment, timing both approachs.